# Operations on child processes C

Tags: c, ubuntu, process, child-process

I want to create a program that:

1. Create child processes
2. List all child processes
3. Read PID to kill one of child processes
4. List all child processes again.

My code:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int c = 0;
    printf("How many: ");
    scanf("%d", & c);

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    ListOfChildren();
    int t;
    printf("Kill child: ");
    scanf("%d", & t);

    char test[50];
    snprintf(test, sizeof(test), "kill -15 %d", t);
    system(test);
    ListOfChildren();
    return 1;

}

int ListOfChildren() {
    char str[50] = "ps -o pid --ppid ";
    char ppid[7];
    sprintf(ppid, "%d", getpid());
    strcat(str, ppid);
    system(str);
    return 1;
}
```

It creates some processes but the last process is not exist? And i can't kill 
not even one... And why it shows 4 process when i want 3?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you fork, your children immediately exit, this is likely that they are already dead when you try to kill them (likely, not mandatory, it depends on the scheduler). Same thing for listing: the processes you see are some of the remaining processes not yet exited and the process "ps" itself, created by your first process.

Comment: so what can i do to make it properly?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question

The last process does not exists because, it is the child process which was forked by the system command in your program and this process is no longer valid once the command returns, hence you are not able to see the process. For more details have a look at the man page of the system command

http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

For the second question, indeed your child processes have finished executing and they have become defunct processes. you can check them in your program by executing

```
ps -ef | grep defunct
```

before you enter some option from "Kill child: ". Then you will see the child processes you forked in the program are defunct.

The reason they have become defunct is

> The parent process has to explicitly take notice of
>   the childs demise by using the wait() system call.

http://en.linuxreviews.org/Defunct_process

You cannot kill them normally with a

```
kill -9 pid
```

That is why the "kill" does not work for you.